# Scala's += method for mutable collections

Tags: scala, collections, queue

What does the += method for scale's mutable collections gets translated to behind the scenes?

For example, if I do += on a mutable queue, is that equivalent to doing an enqueue? Ditto for -=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/Queue.scala#L1), `enqueue` is implemented as:

```
def enqueue(elems: A*): Unit = this ++= elems
```

The `dequeue` code is more complicated and not equivalent to `-=` as there is no `-=` method for a `Queue`.

Answer (score 2):

> What does the += method for scale's mutable collections gets translated to behind the scenes?

It doesn't get translated to anything. It calls the method named `+=` on the given object.

> if I do += on a mutable queue, is that equivalent to doing an enqueue?

If you look at the documentation for `Queue.+=` and `Queue.enqueue`<sup>1</sup> they are the same except that `enqueue` can accept multiple arguments. So yes, `+=` on a mutable queue is equivalent to `enqueue` with a single argument.

---

<sup>1</sup> Quoting from the docs:

> ```
> def +=(elem : A) : Unit
> ```
>
> Inserts a single element at the end of the queue.
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - elem - the element to insert

and

> ```
> def enqueue(elems : A*) : Unit
> ```
>
> Adds all elements to the queue.
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - elems - the elements to add.

Answer (score 1):

`+=` on mutable collections is just a normal method call to `+=`. You may be writing it using infix notation, like this:

```
intList += 5
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
intList.+=(5)
```

There is no `-=` method on `scala.collection.mutable.Queue`.